# Using Laravel to render a view with posts, and retrieve likes from that post

Tags: php, laravel

So I am pretty new to Laravel and PHP, so I had a few questions.

Right now I have a Post model that has many Likes.
Currently I am trying to display all posts on a view using `@foreach($posts as $post)`to retrieve the posts from the controller (this part works already,code for retrieving post content not relevant) I want to display all the likes and dislikes that a post has in a concise manner.

Currently a Like->Like == 1 is a like and a Like->like ==0 is a dislike.

So if a post has 5 dislikes, it will display:
Bob Jane and 4 others Dislike this

Or if it has 2 dislikes:
Jane Doe and John Teach Dislike this

```
            <div class = "dislikes">
                @if(count($post->likes->where('like',0))==0)
                @elseif(count($post->likes->where('like',0))==1)
                    {{ $post->likes->where('like', 0)->first()->user->first_name }} {{ $post->likes->where('like', 0)->first()->user->last_name }} Disikes this
                @elseif(count($post->likes->where('like',0))==2)
                    {{($post->likes->where('like', 0))->first()->user->first_name}} {{($post->likes->where('like', 0))->first()->user->last_name}} and {{($post->likes->where('like', 0))->last()->user->first_name}} {{($post->likes->where('like', 0))->last()->user->last_name}} Dislike This
                @elseif(count($post->likes->where('like', 0))>=4)
                    {{($post->likes->where('like', 0))->first()->user->first_name}} {{($post->likes->where('like', 0))->first()->user->last_name}} and {{count($post->likes->where('like', 0)) - 1}}  Others Like This
                @else
                    @for($i=0;$i<count($post->likes->where('like',0));$i++)
                        @if($i+1 == count($post->likes->where('like',0)))
                            and {{$post->likes->where('like',0))->get()[$i]->user->first_name}} {{$post->likes->where('like',0)->get()[$i]->user->last_name}} Like This
                        @else
                            {{$post->likes->where('like',0)->get()[$i]->user->first_name}} {{$post->likes->where('like',0)->get()[$i]->user->last_name}} , 
                        @endif
                    @endfor
                @endif
            </div>
```

I have played around wiht the code for a few hours, but 
`($post->likes->where('like',0))[$i]->user->first_name` is not working in my for loop, and `($post->likes->where('like',0))[$i]->user->first_name` will not work either.( I have played around with the parentheses placement a bit to try and fix this)

I am at a loss. Any suggestions about a better way I could approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: is the $post->likes->where('like',0) not empty? isn't that should be $post->likes->where('like',0)->get()?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your model or table structure. But let say you have table and model named Post, Like and Dislike. You should have relationship in Post model such as :

```
public function like()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
}

public function dislike()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Dislike::class);
}
```

then you can retrieve data in controller such as

```
$posts = Post::with('like', 'dislike')->get();
return view('view', compact('posts'));
```

now you can loop in view such as

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

     @if($post->like != null)
     <div class = "like">
         @foreach($post->like)
             // render the view here...
         @endforeach
     </div>
     @endif

     @if($post->dislike != null)
     <div class = "dislikes">
         @foreach($post->dislike)
             // render the view here...
         @endforeach
     </div>
     @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: Okay, so my structure is more like

Comment: Okay, I am going to post an edit with a more concise example of my Like class, but I am not sure if I can make this work or not. Right now I am passing all of the posts in the controller, and am trying to checking if the post has a like or not in the view, similar to your code. The problem is that I have one structure for likes, which carry a boolean on whether they are likes or dislikes.

Comment: The problem here is that I am trying to retrieve all the likes and dislikes (which are actually all Like class with a boolean that decides if they are a like or a dislike) on a page that is rendering all Posts that the page is requesting, so I can't push the likes and dislikes separately this way.